# Arduino digitalRead return

Tags: c, arduino

I can't figure out why the returned value of digitalRead() is 0 (LOW), even with the code below.

Any idea?

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  pinMode(4,INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
  Serial.println(digitalRead(4));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If your input pin is connected to a GND for example, why would you expect something different than `0`?

Comment: What @ouah says.  Is the pin high or low?  Stick a meter/scope on it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Arduino Digital Pins documentation at http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins the digitalWrite(4, HIGH) on an input pin does not set the level of the pin. Because of the pinMode(4, INPUT), the digitalWrite(4, HIGH) turns on the processor's internal pullup resistor on pin 4.

digitalRead(4) will show HIGH or LOW, depending on what you have connected to pin 4. If you have nothing connected to pin 4, digitalRead(4) should always return HIGH because the digitalWrite(4, HIGH) connected the internal pullup resistor to it.

So the problem is in the circuit connected to the Arduino; it's not a software problem.  I recommend you follow the advice of @ouah and use a multimeter, oscilloscope, or logic pen to find what the voltage is on pin 4, then debug your circuit connected to pin 4 to find out why that pin is low.

Also, I recommend you move the digitalWrite(4, HIGH) to setup() right after the pinMode(4, INPUT), because it is configuring the pin, and needs to be done only once.